# Why pure tensorflow autoencoder cannot converge, when Keras one fits good

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm newbie at machine learning(and at stackoverflow too). I want to ask for help.
I have two implementations of same two-layer autoencoder for mnist.
First one fits good:

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

def in_pics(pics):
    return np.array(pics, np.float32)/255.

def out_pics(pics):
    npformed = np.array(pics, np.float32)
    samples = np.shape(npformed)[0]
    return np.reshape(npformed, (samples, 784))/255.

(train_data, test_data) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_pics(train_data[0]), out_pics(train_data[0]))).batch(100)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_pics(test_data[0]), out_pics(test_data[0]))).batch(100)

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28,28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(784,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1), 
                                                         bias_initializer  =tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1), 
                                                         bias_initializer  =tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)),
    ]
)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer="adam")
model.fit(x = train_dataset, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_data=test_dataset)
```

[Keras result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3OFu.png)

And I have the same model, same learning procedure, but written in terms of pure tensorflow(almost):

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

def prep_pics(pics):
    npformed = np.array(pics, np.float32)
    samples = np.shape(npformed)[0]
    return np.reshape(npformed, (samples, 784))/255.

batch_size, num_batches = 100, 12000
(train_data, test_data) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
(train_pics_prepared, test_pics_prepared) = (prep_pics(train_data[0]), prep_pics(test_data[0]))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_pics_prepared, train_pics_prepared))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_pics_prepared, test_pics_prepared)).batch(batch_size)

encoder_W = tf.Variable(tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)(shape = [784,128], dtype = tf.float32))
encoder_b = tf.Variable(tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)(shape = [128],dtype = tf.float32))

decoder_W = tf.Variable(tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)(shape = [128,784], dtype = tf.float32))
decoder_b = tf.Variable(tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)(shape = [784],dtype = tf.float32))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
bin_cross = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

@tf.function
def trainstep(X_pack, Y_pack):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch([encoder_W, encoder_b, decoder_W, decoder_b])
        encoded = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X_pack, encoder_W) + encoder_b)
        decoded = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(encoded, decoder_W) + decoder_b)
        loss = bin_cross(decoded, Y_pack)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [encoder_W, encoder_b, decoder_W, decoder_b])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [encoder_W, encoder_b, decoder_W, decoder_b]))

num_samples = len(train_data[0])
epochs = num_batches//(num_samples//batch_size)

for i in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch num {i+1}:")
    dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(num_samples).batch(batch_size)
    for x,y in dataset:
        trainstep(x,y)
```

Loss is never becomes lower than 0.64(First one had 0.07 in the end of education).
[Tensorflow result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt6DA.png).
What I tried:
1.) Change optimizer to Adagrad and even to SGD.
2.) Use other loss - sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits.
3.) Learn more. Especially for SGD.

Cannot find mistake or typo almost for week. Please, help!

Comment: Are you trying to create a model which acts as a generator?

Comment: It's educational code. So, it's just quasi-identity transformation with compression on hidden layer. On next step it will be modified to be denoising autoencoder.

Comment: Your problem might be more complex than searching a matrix, I think this autoencoder is too simple to find complex structures in your images. This might not be done unless you change your structure.

Comment: This structure works perfect in Keras code (first code in my question).

Comment: Hmm yes sorry my bad. Have you tried to create this in a tf custom layer. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models